# OpenLDAP address book in MS Outlook 2010 does not appear automatically, advanced search is needed

Tags: ldap, centos7, openldap, outlook-2010

I currently have an OpenLDAP that runs on Centos 7. I understand that it is configured correctly and working. The problem occurs when I set it to MS Outlook 2010.

- **When opening the list of ldap addresses, it is empty**
  [image: Empty list]
- **It is necessary to enter in advanced search. Enter a space and click the ok button.**
  [image: Advance search]
- **Then you can see the full list (For this example there are only two contacts)**
  [image: Full list]

Is there a way to get the full list to appear when opening the ldap address book?. Has anyone found a solution?

Comment: It depends on the address book implementation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Do you mean that this problem refers to the OpenLDAP configuration?. In that case, where should I start looking?